# Spring Boot with Hikari CP --- Not working while deployment in seperate Tomcat server

Tags: spring-boot

We configured a web application with Hikari Connection Pool via Spring Boot.
Now the problem is that when we deploy it as a war in separate Tomcat Server it picks up the other common dbcp which comes in installed Tomcat.

One way..is to delete those libraries in the installed Tomcat.

Can anyone suggest other options for the same?

Comment: Specify `spring.datasource.type` instead of letting spring decide.

Comment: It worked:  **spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource**

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot, by default, will detect the types of available `DataSource` providers and based on that will create the specific type for that. If you are shipping [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) this will be detected when using a standalone application.

However when deploying to Tomcat this server contains either [Commons DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) (or the tomcat version of that) or [Tomcat JDBC](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html). Then this will take precedence, due to the order that [Spring Boot has preferences](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceBuilder.java#L44).

In the case of Tomcat that will have precedence of Hikari.

The solution is quite easy by telling Spring Boot which `DataSource` type to use. For this specify the `spring.datasource.type` property in your `application.properties`.

```
 spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
```

By doing so Spring Boot will not try to detect the type to use. This way you can also use, non autodetected datasource types like C3P0 or a custom one.

Comment: Yes. Perfect.!! Thanks for the detailed explanation.